# Unable to start Apache-cassandra-4.1.3 getting error like NativeTransportService.java:166 - epoll not available

Tags: cassandra-4.0

I am using the apache-cassandra-4.1.3 but when i am going start the service getting error like
NativeTransportService.java:166 - epoll not available
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty_transport_native_epoll_x86_646819022871921751861.so: /tmp/libnetty_transport_native_epoll_x86_646819022871921751861.so: failed to map segment from shared object

installing Cassandra on Redhat-8.6 and want to overcome this error.